# Data layout for a contract

Tags: website-design, gui-design, interaction-design, design, data

I have visualised a contract. And previously there were less data, so it was like this:

[image]

It was pretty nice, but then we added some more data, and my boss said to regroup it logically (left and right), so I had to add data this way:

[image]

How can I make it less messy, divide it into two logical groups and make it nice have a nice UI? I've got no idea. Maybe you can share some practises or send me some inspiration?

P.S: the header can be changed any way.

Answer (score 1):

- Take all the informative elements in the page and write them on a piece of paper
- Give them numbers according to their importance to the user
- Create an hierarchy between the elements, think: which ones are related and in what way.
- Take a look at dashboards online and get inspired!
- Create [6 up](https://medium.com/@InVisionApp/designing-a-content-model-for-a-better-ux-team-52fef692ba1d) of optional arrangements for this dashboard.

In the end, you might decide you want to emphasize some of the data, use proximity to show their relations etc..

Comment: don't you have any examples of such modal windows in dashobards? can't manage to find any

Comment: It doesn't matter that its a pop up, the hierarchy and relations between the elements is what's important.